# Create a list of Objects C#

Tags: c#

I want to basically create a list of Windows Controls.

Lets say i have a windows control and i want to display 6 of its instances. Now i suppose i can programicly call them up by storing them in the list and display them on the form but what i really want to know is whats the best way to do this.

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4977/exampledhe.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/4977/exampledhe.png)

And for example if i delete an instance from the list. That instance might disapear however its going to have a blank space in its place. Therefore an actual list might work better as it will shift all the remaining ones up. So back to the question is there any way i could store my objects in a datagrid or a list control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9e8s203.aspx) to hold your controls.